# Django - How to show dropdown value instead object?

Tags: python, django

It seems i can't get dropdown value instead object.

[image]

form.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
class FacebookAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    account_description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    facebook_application_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    facebook_application_secret = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ouath_token = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class FacebookFanPage(models.Model):
    facebook_account = models.ForeignKey(FacebookAccount)
    fan_page_description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fan_page_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class PredefinedMessage(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    list_description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Campaign(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    campaign_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    autoresponder_type = (
        ('Send replies to inbox messages','Send replies to inbox messages'),
        ('Post replies to users comments','Post replies to users comments'),
    )
    facebook_account_to_use = models.ForeignKey(FacebookAccount)
    set_auto_reply_for_fan_page = models.ForeignKey(FacebookFanPage)
    message_list_to_use = models.ForeignKey(PredefinedMessage)
    reply_only_for_this_keyword = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

views.py

```
class AutoresponderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = ['campaign_name','facebook_account_to_use','set_auto_reply_for_fan_page','message_list_to_use','reply_only_for_this_keyword']
        exclude = ('user',)

def autoresponder_create(request, template_name='form.html'):
    form = AutoresponderForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form = form.save(commit=False)
        form.user = request.user
        form.save()
        return redirect('autoresponder_list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should implement `__str__` (or `__unicode__` if Python 2) in the object's model.

From Django's [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#str):

> Django uses str(obj) in a number of places. Most notably, to display an object in the Django admin site and as the value inserted into a template when it displays an object. Thus, you should always return a nice, human-readable representation of the model from the **str**() method.

Comment: I prefer this option too, but also you can use manual form rendering in template.

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin Every time that Django tries to display an object, it looks for its Model `__str__` method. That method's return value determines how the object will be displayed.

Comment: I already setup in model. but how about the views.py? which part i need to modify? still showing the object.

Answer (score 0):

Update your models.py like this:

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  campaign_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  autoresponder_type = (
      ('Send replies to inbox messages','Send replies to inbox
       messages'),
      ('Post replies to users comments','Post replies to users comments'),
      )
  facebook_account_to_use = models.ForeignKey(FacebookAccount)
  set_auto_reply_for_fan_page = models.ForeignKey(FacebookFanPage)
  message_list_to_use = models.ForeignKey(PredefinedMessage)
  reply_only_for_this_keyword = models.CharField(max_length=50)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.campaign_name  # or you can use any string value instead of campaign_name
```

Comment: I will try it first.

Comment: I want these three things to be show up, "FacebookAccount .account_description","FacebookFanPage.FacebookAccount .account_description" and "PredefinedMessage. list_name". Please check my updated model.